# TrackChanges inside figure caption

Tags: floats, trackchanges

How can I use the `trackchanges` package macros within a figure caption?

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[margins]{trackchanges}
\addeditor{NH}

\begin{document}

%Non-Problematic
\begin{figure}[htbp]
    \caption{My Caption}
\end{figure}

%Problematic
\begin{figure}[htbp]
    \caption{My Caption with \change[NH]{Old}{New} Text}
\end{figure}

%Problematic
\begin{figure}[htbp]
    \change[NH]{ %
        \caption{My Caption with Old Text}
    }{
        \caption{My Caption with New Text}
    }
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

As identified by @Jagath AR the first problem is the `margins` option, as it uses a `\marginpar` and this not allowed in a float.  Instead of turning of the `margins` option what you can do is redefine the internal commands, so that such corrections in floats are printed inline instead.

For the second problem, with the final figure, not that `\caption` is a fragile command by default, so if included as the argument to another command you should `\protect` it.

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[margins]{trackchanges}

\newcommand{\inlineText}[2]{\footnotesize\UserLabel~#2}
\let\oldmarginText\marginText

\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\marginText}[2]{%
  \@ifundefined{@captype}{\oldmarginText{#1}{#2}}{\inlineText{#1}{#2}}%
}
\makeatother

\addeditor{NH}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[htbp]
    \caption{My Caption}
\end{figure}

An ordinary \change[NH]{change}{difference}.

\begin{figure}[htbp]
    \caption{My Caption with \change[NH]{Old}{New} Text}
\end{figure}

%Problematic
\begin{figure}[htbp]
  \centering
  Figure
   \change[NH]{%
        \protect\caption{My Caption with Old Text}%
    }{%
        \protect\caption{My Caption with New Text}%
    }
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

The package option `margins` is causing the problem as the track changes are written as margin notes. This is not possible for floats. Hence, if you remove the option `margin` the first problem will be fixed. The third figures is also causing the problem. I have now removed third figure and changed package option to `inline` get your MWE generate the PDF.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[inline]{../LatexPackage/trackchanges}
\addeditor{NH}

\begin{document}

%Non-Problematic
\begin{figure}[htbp]
    \caption{My Caption}
\end{figure}

%Problematic
\begin{figure}[htbp]
    \caption{My Caption with \change[NH]{Old}{New} Text}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```